# Fix the position of the div tag

Tags: jquery, html

```
Javascript

$("#col").hover(function (){
   $("#cool").toggle();
});

<div>
<ul id="col">
<li>Sports</li>
<ul id="cool" style="padding-left:0px;display:none">
<li>Tennis</li>
<li>Basketball</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="position:fixed;z-index:-1">
<strong>Wanna be?</strong>
</div>
```

I was trying to create a drowdown menu list.Its working fine as i expected, except one case.When I hover my mouse over the sports word, Tennis and basketball seems to appear but the word wanna be? is pushed down but I want the position to be fixed. I used position-fixed and also z-index as -1 , I dont know if they are used these way but i found them on google

But still the word 'wanna be?' is going down on hover effect but I want it to be fixed and it should be behind the tennis and basketball menu when hover takes effect.

Please help me with these. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: A method to fix (I've currently hardcoded the height at the CSS, but it can be dynamically set using JavaScript/jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/xbjzp/

Comment: well one thing every says position-absolute but using that does it give any harmful effects on different browsers?

Comment: I heard people said never use position absolute go for mostly position relative but just let me know should i go for position absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `position: absolute;` to "cool" UL

```
<div>
<ul id="col">
<li>Sports</li>
<ul id="cool" style="position: absolute;padding-left:0px;display:none">
<li>Tennis</li>
<li>Basketball</li>
</ul>
</ul>
<div style=" z-index:-1">
<strong>Wanna be?</strong>
</div>
</div>
```

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MQtrq/5/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of workarounds for this.

First would be to fix the location of your fixed div by actually specifying it's location with `top` and `left` CSS properties.

Comment: I find overlapping of elements i want it to be behind not overlap

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the position of the #col list to "absolute". That way, the whole list won't take up any space in the HTML document and thus not move stuff around when it changes.

Comment: but  i see the overlapping of elements